# Transform a Promise based function into a sync one

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I have a function which return a promise `getPort()` from the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-port.

I need to change this one so I can stop the code until I don't have the value. like:

```
var port = getPortSync()
```

I can't use generators or await / async cuz the code is actually not in a function.

Basically, I want to do something like `readFileSync` in node.

The reason I'm doing this is that I have a bunch of mocha tests where the variable are declared on the top of the file, I need to retrieve the free port value before the declaration/ initialization of those variables and I want to change the minimum number of lines.

My current attempt is:

```
var getPortSync = function() {
  var port = null
    getPort().then(function(freePort) {
      console.log('port', freePort)
      port = freePort
    })
    while (port === null) {
      console.log('port: ', port)
    }
    return port
  }
```

Comment: Two questions: first, why not just do the Mocha tests inside the `then` of the returned promise? Second, does your attempt work?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that it is not working. 
I put it just to give an idea of what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your approach is not possible.

The code you have there will always have an infinite loop because the assignment of the port happens asynchronously and a `while` loop is a synchronous construct.

If you open the code from the package, the way it is obtaining the port is via an asynchronous callback:

```
server.listen(0, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  // ...
});
```

The main part of the code, [server.address()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address), will only have the port information after the server emits the `listening` event, which means there isn't a way to obtain this synchronously.

Perhaps you can wrap the test in the `then` of the promise?

```
getPort().then((port) => {
  // your test code
});
```

You could also use mocha's test hooks (which work great with promises) to obtain the port before a test block:

```
describe('my-test', function() {

  let port;
  before(() => getPort().then((p) => {
    port = p;
  });
```

Or if you know the port or it's always the same, perhaps you could just hard code it in the test.

Comment: You can also just hold on to the promise.  `let portPromise; before(() => portPromise = getPort())`.  Then, in your tests, you would start out with `portPromise.then((port) => { ... })`.

Comment: basically, the port WAS always the same, but it is used to spin up the server. So right now my  tests  work if you run them alone, but not if you run them together!.

We don't want a random number to avoid collision, and we don't want to change them manually for every test.

The approach you suggested (moving the code inside the .then) is what I'm doing now, but it is long and I was trying to find a way to avoid it :)

Comment: @jurgo yeah, unfortunately you have to work around javascript's async nature. Async/await would probably give the cleanest looking code as in it would look almost synchronous but since you cannot use it, the only other approach is through promises directly.